# The product of a generator with itself

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to iterate over the product of a generator with itself, excluding the diagonal.  I'm attempting to use `itertools.tee` to consume the same generator twice

```
def pairs_exclude_diagonal(it):
    i1, i2 = itertools.tee(it, 2)
    for x in i1:
        for y in i2:
            if x != y:
                yield (x, y)
```

This does not work

```
In [1]: for (x, y) in pairs_exclude_diagonal(range(3)):
   ...:     print(x, y)
0 1
0 2
```

The [documentation for tee](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) states:

> Return n independent iterators from a single iterable.

What's the proper way to do this?

(I'm using python3.6.1)

Answer (score 8):

It looks like you want to use [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations).

```
In [1]: import itertools

In [2]: for x, y in itertools.permutations(range(3), 2):
   ...:     print(x, y)
   ...:     
0 1
0 2
1 0
1 2
2 0
2 1
```

If you *really* want to do it using `tee`, you will have to turn the second iterable into a `list` so that it is not exhausted on the second time through the outer `for` loop:

```
In [14]: def pairs_exclude_diagonal(it):
    ...:     i1, i2 = itertools.tee(it, 2)
    ...:     l2 = list(i2)
    ...:     for x in i1:
    ...:         for y in l2:
    ...:             if x != y:
    ...:                 yield (x, y)
    ...:                 

In [15]: for (x, y) in pairs_exclude_diagonal(range(3)):
    ...:     print(x, y)
    ...:     
0 1
0 2
1 0
1 2
2 0
2 1
```

Note that this is pretty pointless, since calling `list` on an iterator loads it into memory and defeats the purpose of having an iterator in the first place.

Comment: This answer is a bit better than mine (which I'll keep up for the explanation of the issue with the questioner's code, not so much for my solution). I'd say your `tee` solution is pretty pointless though. If you're going to call `list` on one of the iterators, you might as well just call it on the `it` argument directly and use it for both loops.

Comment: @Blckknght I 100% agree that the `tee` solution is pointless.  I thought about explaining that... but then I didn't.  I'll add a bit about that now.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you're trying to reuse the `i2` iterator. After it's been iterated once, it's exhausted and so you won't be able to iterate on it again. When you try, it yields nothing.

I think rather than `tee` (which is not very efficient for this purpose anyway), you should use `itertools.product` to generate all pairs (before filtering out the ones you want to skip):

```
def pairs_exclude_diagonal(it):
    for x, y in itertools.product(it, repeat=2):
        if x != y:
            yield (x, y)
```

Comment: I had somehow got it in my head that I had tried `product` and it had the same issue.  Just tried and it works just fine.  DoH.

Comment: Also, of course on using the `it2` twice.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I get an unpacking error for this recipe unless I use `repeat=2` in `product`. This works as-is for you?

Comment: I had to do the same.  The docs for `product` also clearly specify to provide that argument when "compute[ing] the product of an iterable with itself".

Comment: Whoops, yeah, that's an error. I'll edit the answer. I think @SethMMorton's answer using `itertools.permutations` is probably better than doing filtering on the values yielded by `product`.